# Programmatically change property value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
 <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/session-timeout-1.do" />
 </beans:bean/>
```

I have 2 different session-timeout pages for different types of users. After a user logs in, the value of the property may have to change from "/session-timeout-1.do" to "/session-timeout-2.do" after checking the type of the user.

I am wondering that is there an API that can change the property value at runtime?

Or is it possible to have a variable in the config file, e.g.

```
<beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="${time-out-url}">
```

where variable "time-out-url" can be set programmatically?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. This bean is invoked in order to authenticate users. So unless I miss something, when it is used, you don't have any clue of what type of user this bean is called for, since the user is not authenticated yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` class and provide your own logic.

See the class source here:
http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/rwinchs-spring-security/blobs/2d271666a406a4409def9afcd73ea340c40a7a88/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

Specifically the method:

```
determineUrlToUseForThisRequest
```

which "Allows subclasses to modify the login form URL that should be applicable for a given request".